# Minimal setup for Glossaries including short forms?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra, glossary

I did not find any tutorial or question, which might help me with this issue.

I am using
`\usepackage[acronym, nomain, automake, nopostdot, shortcuts]{glossaries-extra}`

`\makeglossaries`

`\printglossary[style=list]`

To print glossaries. Some are acronyms and I've added a `short` (and/or) `text` field to the entries.

I want a Glossary which is like

- **National Aeronautics and Space Administration (*NASA*)** The National Aeronautics and Space Administration is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research.

The order and formatting is not important, but what is the minimal setup to achieve a glossary to include short forms?

---

```
\newglossaryentry{nasa}
{
    name={National Aeronautics and Space Administration},
    text={NASA},
    short={NASA},
    description={The National Aeronautics and Space Administration is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research.}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found a solution for my problem:

```
\usepackage[acronym, nomain, automake, section=chapter]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
    \setglossarystyle{list}%
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \item \textsf{\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1} 
        \ifglshasshort{##1}%
        {(\glsfmttext{##1})}%
        {}%
        }}} \space \glossentrydesc{##1}\par
    }%
}

\newglossaryentry{nasa}
{
    name={National Aeronautics and Space Administration},
    text={NASA},
    short={NASA},
    description={The National Aeronautics and Space Administration is an independent agency of the U.S. federal government responsible for the civil space program, aeronautics research, and space research.}
}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[style=mystyle, type=\acronymtype]
```